# How do I call extension methods from outside the class they are defined in?

Tags: extension-methods, kotlin

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract fun String.extension(x: Char)
}

class Derived : Base() {
    override fun String.extension(x: Char) {
        // Calling lots of methods on String, hence extension method
        println("${first()} $length ${last()} ${firstOrNull { it == x }} ...")
    }
}
```

Calling the extension method from Java is trivial:

```
Base o = new Derived();
o.extension("hello world", 'l');
```

But I can't figure out how to do it in pure Kotlin. Neither `String` nor `Base` seems to have the `extension` method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First, note that an extension function defined as a member requires two receivers, one is an instance of the enclosing class (*dispatch receiver*, usually `this` of the enclosing class) and the other is the instance of the type that the function extends (*extension receiver*). This is documented [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members).

So, to call such a function from outside the class you have to provide two receivers. Kotlin [doesn't have any syntax](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10468) to do that explicitly like `(x, "abc").stringExtension()`, but you can provide the dispatch receiver implicitly using an [extension lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver):

```
class C(val name: String) {
    fun String.extended() = this + " extended by " + name
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val c = C("c")
    with(c) { println("abc".extended()) }
}
```

<sup>[(runnable demo of this code)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/o07cqupkc2lbv8d3d4vvm2t9in/6rc9a81na5ki85lc1kset35jkl)</sup>

In the [`with(...) { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) block, `c` becomes the implicit receiver, thus allowing you to use it as a dispatch receiver in `C` member extensions. This would work with any other function that uses functional types with receivers: `apply`, `run`, `use` etc.

In your case, it would be `with(o) { "hello world".extension('l') }`

As [@KirillRakhman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615306/kirill-rakhman) noted, an extension receiver of an extension function for `C` can also be implicitly used as a dispatch receiver for the extensions defined inside `C`:

```
fun C.someExtension() = "something".extended()
```

Comment: What I meant is, not only extension _lambdas_ but also extension _functions_ can be used to provide the implicit receiver. Example: `fun C.inScope() = "".extended()`

Answer (score 1):

To decale an extension method outside the class using it, you should **NOT** implement it inside a class, and you should do like this:

```
package com.sample.test

import java.io.File

fun File.folderLength() : Long {
    return 0L
}
```

So in your class that call this method:

```
package com.sample.util

import com.sample.test.*
import java.io.File

class foo{
    fun getFolderSize(url: String) : Long{
        var file = new File("...")
        var length = file.folderLength()
        return length
    }
}
```

Hope this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your extension function is defined only inside of Base/Derived class. See [Declaring Extensions as Members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members).

```
abstract class Base {
    abstract fun String.extension(x: Char)
}

class Derived : Base() {
    override fun String.extension(x: Char) {
        // Calling lots of methods on String, hence extension method
        println("${first()} $length ${last()} ${firstOrNull { it == x }} ...")
    }

    fun callExtension(c: Char) {
        "hello".extension(c)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val base = Derived()
    base.callExtension('h')
}
```

Comment: There actually is a way to call a *public* member extension from outside the class: using an implicit receiver instance of that class.